# MYSQL Tables Picky About Fields?

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I am having issues with php and mysql once again. I have a database setup with the table users and I want to make a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE {value1} {value2}` etc...but the problem is that the 3 fields I want to compare are not in order in the table and when trying the SELECT query, the result vairable($result) is NOT returned properly(!$result). Is there a way to check multiple fields in a mysql table that have fields in between them? Here is an example of what I want to accomplish:
A mysql table called users contains these fields: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l and m`.
I want to make a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`users`WHERE a='$_SESSION[user]' and d='$_SESSION[actcode]' and j='$_SESSION[email]'` but the statement in quotes is my query and it always executes the `if (!$result) { error("An error has occurred in processing your request.");}` statement. What am I doing wrong? On the contrary, whenever I try the statement using only one field, ex a, the code works fine! This is an annoying problem that I cannot seem to solve! I have posted the code below, also note that the error function is a custom function I made and is working perfectly normal.

```
<?php
include "includefunctions.php";
$result = dbConnect("program");
if (!$result){
    error("The database is unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later.");

} else {

ob_start();
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user']) or empty($_SESSION['password']) or empty($_SESSION['activationcode']) or empty($_SESSION['email'])){
    error("This information is either corrupted or was not submited through the proper protocol. Please check the link and try again!");
} elseif ($_SESSION['password'] != "password"){
     error("This information is either corrupted or was not submited through the proper protocol. Please check the link and try again!");
} else {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION[user]' and `activationcode`='$_SESSION[activationcode]' and `email`='$_SESSION[email]'";/*DOES NOT MATTER WHAT ORDER THESE ARE IN, IT STILL DOES NOT WORK!*/
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        error("A database error has occurred in processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.");/*THIS IS THE ERROR THAT WONT GO AWAY!*/
    } elseif (mysql_result($result,0,0)==1){/*MUST EQUAL 1 OR ACCOUNT IS INVALID!*/
        echo "Acount activated!";
    } else {
            error("Account not activated.");    
    }
}
}
ob_end_flush();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Try looking at mysql_error immediately after the query has been executed - that'll tell you what MySQl thinks is wrong. The order of your conditions should not be significant.

Comment: order dosent matter. there is something else wrong.

Comment: I tried both answers and neither of them worked. But I am seeing an issue in the "'" character as the double quotes are fine but for some reason the link in the email has an extra single quote after it. BUT that quote is required for encapsing the string. Also, when ran without the quote, it still does not run correctly. GRRRRR THIS ISSUE IS MAKING ME ANGRY WHY WON'T IT JUST WORK!

Comment: Here is the mysql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jammer'' AND `activationcode`=''37f01014e3a648d9609299db4485e138''' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your `$_SESSION` variables in curly brackets `{}` and add `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of your query -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `activationcode`='{$_SESSION['activationcode']}' and `email`='{$_SESSION['email']}'";/*DOES NOT MATTER WHAT ORDER THESE ARE IN, IT STILL DOES NOT WORK!*/
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

> store your session value in another varibles then make query , i think
>   it's work proper

```
$usr=$_SESSION['user'];
$acod=$_SESSION['activationcode'];
$eml=$_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$usr' and `activationcode`='$acod' and `email`='$eml'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```